# JS debug - var bankroll value is way off

Tags: javascript, debugging

This is the first JS program I've ever written so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm getting a bankroll value that is WAY off.  For instance if you use

runs=1, start=5000, bonusMultiplier = anything between 0 and 1

I am usually getting a value for bankroll of 5000500. I've gone over the code for hours now but can't figure it out. In the number 5000500, 5000 comes from var start, and 500 comes from var betsize.  I don't know how they get combined into one number.  Please help!

```
var profit = 0;
var runs = prompt("How many runs?");
var start = prompt("Starting chips?");
var bonusMultiplier = prompt("Bonus? Use decimal.");
var inAmt = (start/(1+bonusMultiplier));
var bonusValue = bonusMultiplier * inAmt;


function simulation(){

var bankroll = start;


function makeBet(){
if (bankroll === 0){
    console.log("BUSTO IN " + hands + "HANDS");
    betsize = 0;

} else if(bankroll <=50) {
betsize = bankroll;
} else if (bankroll<1000) {
betsize = 1/2 * bankroll;
} else {
betsize = 500;
}

var odds = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000+1);
//console.log(odds);

if (odds>507) {
bankroll = bankroll + betsize;
} else {
bankroll = bankroll - betsize;
}
console.log("bankroll " + bankroll);
console.log("betsize " + betsize);
}

/*var hands=prompt("hands");
console.log("hands " + hands)


for (i = 0; i < hands; i++) {
makeBet();
}*/

while (bankroll >0) {
if (bankroll>=7000) {break;}
makeBet();
}

if (bankroll === 0) {
profit -= inAmt;
}
if (bankroll >=7000) {
profit += bankroll;
profit -= inAmt;
}}

for (i=0; i<runs; i++) {
simulation();
}
console.log("start " + start, " bonus multiplier " + bonusMultiplier, " in amount "+ inAmt, " bonus value "+ bonusValue);
console.log("profit after " + runs + " runs = $" + profit);
```

Comment: you need to use parseFloat or some other method to ensure the values retrieved using prompt are treated as numbers rather than strings

Answer (score 1):

`start` is being interpreted as string. If you sum a string and a number, the number gets converted into a string, which is then concated with the other one. Change

```
start = prompt("Starting chips?");
```

to

```
start = parseFloat(prompt("Starting chips?"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume using,

```
var runs = parseFloat( prompt("How many runs?") );
var start = parseFloat( prompt("Starting chips?") );
var bonusMultiplier = parseFloat( prompt("Bonus? Use decimal.") );
```

will resolve your issue.

Use `parseInt()` if you need to return an integer.

prompts accept input as `strings`.
You need numbers if you want to use math operators.

Data types are mostly the error issues for starters, read about them even if you know. Grasp, and they almost never bug you again.